zlib error when running cdk bootstrap in wsl2
I am trying to bootstrap a new aws environment using cdk bootstrap. Nevertheless, I get the following error:
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  ZlibError: zlib: unexpected end of file
      at Unzip.write (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3565:36)
      at Unzip.flush (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3534:22)
      at Unzip.end (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3540:22)
      at UnpackSync.end (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:5663:37)
      at Pipe.end (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:2969:46)
      at [emitEnd2] (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3246:23)
      at [emitEnd] (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3233:86)
      at ReadStreamSync.emit (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3196:41)
      at ReadStreamSync.emit (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:1710:34)
      at [maybeEmitEnd] (/tmp/tmpqmw0uq1d/lib/program.js:3185:26)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 4, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 1422, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/_jsii/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    import aws_cdk.asset_awscli_v1._jsii
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aws_cdk/asset_awscli_v1/_jsii/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __jsii_assembly__ = jsii.JSIIAssembly.load(
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 55, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    self.provider.load(LoadRequest(name=name, version=version, tarball=tarball))
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 354, in load
    return self._process.send(request, LoadResponse)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 342, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: zlib: unexpected end of file

My setup looks as follows:

Using wsl2 in windows

cdk version: 2.147.3 (build 32f0fdb)

node version: v22.3.0

npm version: 10.8.1


uninstalling and installing everything again is not helping
